# If an application is built on a 32-bit machine, when run on a 64-bit machine, how does it look for DLLs?

Tags: windows, dll, vb6, 32bit-64bit

If an application is built on a 32-bit machine, when run on a 64-bit machine, how does it know the **.dll** is in **C:\Program Files (x86)** instead of **C:\Program Files** or it doesn't?

**ERROR SUMMARY** 
**[SCRIPT]:** File not found: **C:\Program Files\Common Files...\abc.dll**.

However, in my 64-bit machine, abc.dll is in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files...\abc.dll**

If it doesn't, where do I adjust the path because apparently it's not in the application's code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can cross-compile in either direction so being built on a 32-bit machine doesn't necessarily mean anything.  It is really an issue of running 32-bit code on a 64-bit machine.  In this case, there is a 32-bit emulation layer on 64-bit installations called [Wow64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Part of this is file system redirection, which redirects file system requests from 32-bit programs.  In this case, trying to access "C:\Program Files" from 32-bit code will transparently redirect to "C:\Program Files (x86)".

Comment: In that case, that must be some other problems that causes this error. Could it because the database driver or config. is different for 32 and 64 bits OS?

Comment: There is no file system redirection on Program Files.  However, if a 32-bit application properly asks the operating system where the program files folder is (which might after all have a localized name) it will be told to use `Program Files(x86)`.

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't?

No part of the [default search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) checks anywhere in `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` *unless* it is because the directory of the application is under one of those folders.

If you are getting that error from a 32bit application then something is set up unusually (like overriding the default install location under `Program Files (x86)`).

Comment: In that case, that must be some other problems that causes this error. Could it because the database driver or config. is different for 32 and 64 bits OS?

Comment: @HoKy22 Certainly anything that runs in process needs to match the executable, thus usually requiring both 32 and 64 bit versions on 64biut Windows.